# DataTables warning - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am working with DataTable.js and trying to implement into MVC. I've written code as per below:

**View:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="demo">
        <h2>Index</h2>
        <table id="myDataTable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Event Name</th>
                    <th>Event Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("AjaxHandler","DataTable")",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "EventID" },
                    { "sName": "EventName" },
                    { "sName": "EventTypeTitle" }
                ]
            });
        }); 
    </script>
}
```

And **Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return View();
}


public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
      return Json(new
      {
           sEcho = param.sEcho,
           iTotalRecords = getAllEvent().Count(),
           iTotalDisplayRecords = getAllEvent().Count(),
           aaData = getAllEvent()
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private List<EventModel> getAllEvent()
{
      List<EventModel> model = new List<EventModel>();
      EventModel model1 = new EventModel { EventID = 1, EventName = "Event 1", EventType = 1, EventTypeTitle = "General" };
      model1.EventScheduleList = new List<EventScheduleModel> { new EventScheduleModel {EventScheduleID = 1 }, new EventScheduleModel { EventScheduleID = 2 } };
      model.Add(model1);
      return model;
}
```

> I am getting DataTables warning: table id=myDataTable - Requested
>   unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about
>   this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

As I research about the error I could find that this particular error is occur when data is not in correct manner. but, when I check response, I am getting correct data.

> Is it because I have returned more numbers of columns which are used
>   in View? or Do I send integer value in JSON?

I've attached fiddle link as well:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/MEoqg8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make very small change in you JacaScript code which goes like this, which means instead of using `sName` you need to use `data` inside `aoColumns` array.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("AjaxHandler","Home")',
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                {
                    "data": "EventID",
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                        return '<a href=\"Details/' +
                            oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                    }
                },
                { "data": "EventName" },
                { "data": "EventTypeTitle" }
            ]
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

You can check a fork from your fiddle here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sXghO

Comment: Yeah. It working. I was following Codeproject Tutorial in which they have used sName.

Comment: Yeah, It's just an update of `DataTables` library which might causing this issue.